# Parallax images issue in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I'm doing a project with parallaxing 3 images based on the mouse movement.
In Chrome and internet explorer it works fine but my problem is firefox!

The parallax mouse movement effect doesnt work like it should for firefox, how can I solve the problem. firefox makes the effect only work up and down movement like if you scroll automatically with the mouse. The effect should rather be like it moves with the mouse like if the mouse is a camera in 3D space.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var movementStrength = 15;
  var height = movementStrength / $(window).height();
  var width = movementStrength / $(window).width();
  $("#logo-image").mousemove(function(e) {
    var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
    var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
    var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
    var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;
    $('#logo-image').css("background-position", newvalueX + "px " + newvalueY + "px");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var movementStrength = 10;
  var height = movementStrength / $(window).height();
  var width = movementStrength / $(window).width();
  $("#mos").mousemove(function(e) {
    var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
    var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
    var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
    var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;
    $('#mos').css("background-position", newvalueX + "px " + newvalueY + "px");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var movementStrength = 5;
  var height = movementStrength / $(window).height();
  var width = movementStrength / $(window).width();
  $("#bottom-image").mousemove(function(e) {
    var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
    var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
    var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
    var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;
    $('#bottom-image').css("background-position", newvalueX + "px " + newvalueY + "px");
  });
});
```

```css
#bottom-image {
  background: url('bgpalms.jpg') -25px -50px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: calc(100% + 50px);
}

#logo-image {
  background: url('palms_kungen_1.png') -25px -50px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: calc(100% + 50px);
}

#mos {
  background: url('mos.png') -25px -50px;
  /*margin: 0 auto 0 auto;*/
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: calc(100% + 50px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bottom-image">
  <div id="mos">
    <div id="logo-image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need to see  the associated HTML and CSS too, so that we can create an MCVE. The JS alone isn't really enough to see what's happening in order to rectify any problems

Comment: Also note that you don't need 3 separate document.ready event handlers, you can place all logic within a single one.

Comment: Edited the question so now it should be everything.